# DataTemplate can't find type because unknown namespace, Xamarin.Forms UWP

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, datatemplate

I'm working with Xamarin.Forms and I was trying to make a Custom Renderer for TabbedPage (UWP) and it kind of works... But when I try to create a new DataTemplate in C# referencing another Custom Renderer I get an error and I can't find any solution to that.

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetStyledHeaderTemplate() {
    StringBuilder tpl = new StringBuilder();
    tpl.Append("<DataTemplate xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation\"");
    tpl.Append(" xmlns:tint=\"clr-namespace:MyNamespace.UI;assembly=MyNamespace\"");
    tpl.Append(" xmlns:x=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml\">");
    tpl.Append("<StackPanel Margin=\"0\" Padding=\"5, 0\" VerticalAlignment=\"Top\">");
    tpl.Append("<tint:ImageTinted TintColor=\"White\" Source=\"{Binding UWPIcon}\" Width=\"24\" Height=\"24\" Margin=\"0, 5, 0, 0\" />");
    tpl.Append("<TextBlock Padding=\"0\" Margin=\"0, 0, 0, 4\"");
    tpl.Append(" Text=\"{Binding Title}\" FontFamily=\"Segoe UI\" Foreground=\"White\" HorizontalAlignment=\"Center\" FontSize=\"13\" />");
    tpl.Append("</StackPanel>");
    tpl.Append("</DataTemplate>");
    return (Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(tpl.ToString());
}
```

The code works fine when I don't call

```
<tint:ImageTinted />
```

from the DataTemplate and ImageTinted works in other places.

Please, help!

**Error:**

```
Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  HResult=0x802B000A
  Message=The text associated with this error code could not be found.

The type 'ImageTinted' was not found because 'clr-namespace:MyNamespace.UI;assembly=MyNamespace' is an unknown namespace. [Line: 1 Position: 339]
  Source=
  StackTrace:
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlReader.Load(String xaml)
   at MyNamespace.UWP.StyledTabbedPageRenderer.GetStyledHeaderTemplate() in D:\...\MyNamespace.UWP\UI\Renderers\StyledTabbedPageRenderer.cs:line 91
   at MyNamespace.UWP.StyledTabbedPageRenderer.OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e) in D:\...\MyNamespace.UWP\UI\Renderers\StyledTabbedPageRenderer.cs:line 35
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.TabbedPageRenderer.SetElement(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.CreateRenderer(VisualElement element)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementExtensions.GetOrCreateRenderer(VisualElement self)
   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.Platform.<SetCurrent>d__51.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tpl.Append(" xmlns:tint=\"clr-namespace:MyNamespace.UI;assembly=MyNamespace\"");
```

Change MyNamespace.UI to the name of your namespace
assembly should be the name of your assembly (In this case the name of your PCL project

Comment: I've tried all the combinations of the namespace and get the same error :/

Answer (score 0):

In the UWP project containing your renderer, assuming MyNamespace.UI is the namespace of class ImageTinted and the assembly is referenced, replace this

```
tpl.Append(" xmlns:tint=\"clr-namespace:MyNamespace.UI;assembly=MyNamespace\"");
```

with the following:

```
tpl.Append(" xmlns:tint=\"using:MyNamespace.UI\"");
```

For example, if `ImageTinted` in the UWP project look like this:

```
<UserControl
x:Class="MyNamespace.UI.ImageTinted"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<TextBlock Text="ImageTinted"/>
```

This should load the template in the `XamlReader.Load` statement.

Debug by setting a breakpoint at the end brace of `GetStyledHeaderTemplate()`, i.e. after the `return` statement. No exceptions from `XamlReader.Load` should be observed at this point.

If you still have errors then you should look into the `ImageTinted` class.

Here is an example UWP Renderer for TabbedPage:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace MyRenderer.UWP
{
  public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
  {
    protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.HeaderTemplate = GetStyledHeaderTemplate();
        }
    }
  }

  private Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate GetStyledHeaderTemplate()
  {
    string xaml = @"
<DataTemplate 
    xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation""
    xmlns:x=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml""
    xmlns:tint=""using:MyNamespace.UI"">
<StackPanel Orientation=""Horizontal"">
    <tint:ImageTinted Source=""{Binding Icon}""/>
    <TextBlock Text=""{Binding Title}"" FontFamily=""Segoe UI"" 
FontSize=""13"" />
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>";

    return (Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate)XamlReader.Load(xaml);
  }
}
```

Comment: Tested your solution but got the same result. Pasting tmpXaml into MainPage gave me some errors:
- The specified value cannot be assigned to the collection. The following type was expected: "UIElement"

and

- A value of type 'ImageTinted' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'

Comment: I even replaced ImageTinted with other Custom controls but it did't work.  ImageTinted is a C# custom rendered control that otherwise works fine. It's just when I try to call it from a custom TabbedPageRenderer for UWP that it fails.